# Setting entity reference field value in Drupal 8 programatically

Tags: 8, entities

I have this following code that creates a node in the page.

```
$data = array(
  'type' => 'post',
  'field_post' => [
      'value' => 'test',
      'format' => 'basic_html',
    ],
  'field_visibility' => 1, 
  'user_id' => $uid
);
$node = Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('post')
  ->create($data);
$node->save();
```

I have another field `field_pattern` that is an entity reference for another content type. How can I properly set it inside my code?

Since with creating the content from the site when dealing with Entity reference field selects autocomplete to Title, then I tried to test this but fails. Meaning no value is set to entity reference.

```
$title = $entity->label();
$data = array(
  'type' => 'post',
  'field_post' => [
      'value' => 'test',
      'format' => 'basic_html',
    ],
  'field_pattern' => $title, // this is the entity reference field
  'field_visibility' => 1, 
  'user_id' => $uid
);
$node = Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('post')
  ->create($data);
$node->save();
```

Comment: Are you creating a new node or new bundle?

Comment: Generic answer: Create whatever you want to create in the UI. Load it and do var_dump($entity->toArray()), those are the raw values, and whatever you get there you can also set on those entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are creating a node with reference field, see below code:

```
 use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
 $node = Node::create([
   'type' => 'post',
   'field_post' => [
     'value' => 'test',
     'format' => 'basic_html',
   ],
   'field_pattern' => [
      'target_id' => $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY, // Here just provide referenced entity id.
   ],
   'field_visibility' => 1, 
   'user_id' => $uid
 ]);
 $node->save();
```

If you are are not creating node then just replace your field_pattern like below:

```
'field_pattern' => [
   'target_id' => $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY, // Here just provide referenced entity id.
],
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest and response on this. Im creating a Post content node. Its not a regular node/content type, but a Post Type from  OpenSocial profile. I have to follow  my code to create one else I would  get error since its not a Node. What is the example  value for the $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY?

Comment: Basically, the entity reference is just another content. In web  ui,  we select the title to provide value for the entity reference field. But im not sure with $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY, where to get this value?

Comment: $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY will the ID of your referenced entity. Suppose you are referring a taxonomy in that field, that $ID_REFERENCE_ENTITY would be TID of that taxonomy. Hope this helps..

Comment: Oh that simple! It works like a charm! Perfect! Thank you so much!